# How mock method that called in testing method for Android?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I write tests for my android application and I need to mock a method from my class, that is called in a method I test.
This is my class:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
.....
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            if (!isAppOnForeground(this)) {
                DoSomeThing();
            }
        }
    }

public boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
       return isAppOnForeground;
    }
}
```

I want to test `onMessageReceived` method when `isAppOnForeground` returns true and false.

I try

```
@Test
public void onMessageReceived() {
MyFirebaseMessagingService mockMyFirebaseMessagingService = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(MyFirebaseMessagingService.class);
when(mockMyFirebaseMessagingService.isAppOnForeground(any(Context.class))).thenReturn(false);
mockMyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
...
}
```

But when I run this test, I don't see call in method `onMessageReceived` (breakpoints don't work).
How can I mock `isAppOnForeground` and call `onMessageReceived`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see `onMessageReceived()` method is running because it's not.

```
MyFirebaseMessagingService mockMyFirebaseMessagingService = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(MyFirebaseMessagingService.class);
```

You're creating a mock, an empty mock, that does not know anything about the implementation of the original class.

You want to use `spy()` instead. Try this:

```
MyFirebaseMessagingService myFirebaseMessagingService = new MyFirebaseMessagingService();
MyFirebaseMessagingService mockMyFirebaseMessagingService = org.mockito.Mockito.spy(myFirebaseMessagingService);
doReturn(false).when(mockMyFirebaseMessagingService).isAppOnForeground(any(Context.class));
mockMyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
```